# AngularJS Pagination/Filtering Large Data

Tags: angularjs

I m using WebAPI for extracting close to 80 K records and render it to the page using inhouse built AngularJS table component.

The API call is made in the on-change event of the table Component. For the initial load of data, its fine but for every pagination and filtering , it hits the server and fetches the 60K records which consumes quite a time.

Was it advisable solution to keep 60k records in memory and work on it? Any recommendations

```
   onChange: function (filterCondition) {
                var that = this;

                DynamicTableData.query(filterCondition, APIurl,function (records) {

                    that.totalRecordsCount = records.totalRecordsCount;
                    that.records = records.data;
```

Comment: Thanks @Akram. But was it recommended to use local storage, will it not affect memory? and also i m using the same onchange event for all the tables used in my application.. in that case, would i end up in creating multiple local storage? could you share some insight into how it can be done

Comment: I thing https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache is solution of your problem